# How SelectKBest(chi2, k=5).fit(x_train, y_train) calculates the scoring?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, feature-selection

Input Data:

```
id    diagnosis    Invoice No    Test Name
111      M              2            2
112      B              6            5
113      M              4            6
```

Code:

```
#2) Univariate feature selection and random forest classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
# find best scored features

select_feature = SelectKBest(chi2, k=1).fit(x_train, y_train)

print('Score list:', select_feature.scores_)
print('Feature list:', x_train.columns)
p.append(x_train.columns.values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
{'Test Name': 0.09090909090909091}
```

Now my question is how it calculates the scoring?

Comment: You are choosing Chi-squared as the scoring when you write: `SelectKBest(chi2, k=1)`. Are you asking what chi-squared is?

Comment: My question is how chi2 generate this score? For this result how 0.09090909090909091 this number generate?